# How do I describe a calculated default value with RAML?

Tags: api-design, raml

If I'm describing an API in RAML and I have a request object schema that has a property with a default value that is calculated (rather than explicitly set), how would I describe that?

For instance, let's say I have an integer value whose default value is the current UTC time in epoch format, how would I describe that?

Answer (score 0):

The **default** keyword is used to specify default values. But there is no way to say that it is a calculated value, other than stating it in the description.

```
foo:
    description: This value is calculated somehow
    type:        integer
    minimum:     10
    maximum:     200
    default:     30
    example:     50
```

Comment: That's not really what I mean. I mean that it is calculated on the fly if not provided by the user, i.e. it doesn't have a static value.

Comment: Again, there is no way to specify that it is a calculated value in RAML